# CSS - css grid-column-gap only on inner columns

Tags: css

Is it possible to use grid-column-gap but only have the gap on the inner columns and not on the last column

In the example here you can see the gap is on the last column but I don't want a gap on the last column

```css
  
@media (min-width: 400px) {
    .wrapper{ 
      border: 2px solid blue;
      padding: 5px;
      max-width: 500px;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 70% 30%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      grid-column-gap: 50px
  }
}

.block{
  height: 100px;
}

.block-1{
  background: red;
}

.block-2{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='block block-1'></div>
  <div class='block block-2'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your problem is with a gap on the last column.
I think you should change your .wrapper to this:

```
grid-template-columns: 7fr 3fr;
```